# Table the LCM of an increasing list

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to create a table showing `LCM[1,2]`, `LCM[1,2,3]`, `LCM[1,2,3,4], ..., LCM[1,2,3,...,m]`. I figure I should be able to use `Range` to do this, but I can't quite figure out how. My attempt so far:

```
Module[{m = 10}, 
  table = Table[Range[n], {n, 1, m}]; 
  TableForm[
    Table[{n, LCM[table[[n]]]}, {n, 1, m}], 
    TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "LCM[1\[Rule]n]"}}]]
```

This doesn't work. I suspect it's something to do with how the list `table` is 'wrapped' in parentheses `{{...},{...},...,{...}}` but I'm not really sure.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** Much faster alternative using `FoldList`:

```
ClearAll[lCM]
lCM = FoldList[LCM] @* Range

r3 = lCM[10^4]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.023673, Null}

versus `lcm` from Carl's answer:

```
Clear[lcm];
lcm[1] = 1;
lcm[n_] := lcm[n] = LCM[n, lcm[n - 1]]

r2 = lcm /@ Range[10^4]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.060979, Null}

```
r3 == r2
```

> True

**Original answer:**

Use `LCM @@ table[[n]]` instead of `LCM[table[[n]]]` to get

[image]

An alternative way using a single `Table`:

```
Module[{m = 10}, 
 TableForm[
    Table[{n, LCM @@ Range[n]}, {n, 1, m}], 
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "LCM[1\[Rule]n]"}}]]
```

Comment: Fab. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Richard, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 4):

If you're interested in doing this for large values of `m`, then it would be much faster to use a memoized version:

```
lcm[1] = 1;
lcm[n_] := lcm[n] = LCM[n, lcm[n-1]]
```

An example showing it works:

```
lcm /@ Range[10]
```

> {1, 2, 6, 12, 60, 60, 420, 840, 2520, 2520}

reproducing kglr's answer. Now, for a much larger value of `m`:

```
r1 = Table[LCM @@ Range[n], {n, 1, 10^4}]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {35.862, Null}

Using `lcm` instead:

```
Clear[lcm];
lcm[1]=1;
lcm[n_]:=lcm[n]=LCM[n,lcm[n-1]]
r2 = lcm /@ Range[10^4]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.04681, Null}

Check:

```
r1 === r2
```

> True

So, about 1000 times faster than the non-memoized version.